# What is the difference between View arg0 and View v?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wrote an xml file for my code and it has 2 buttons. However, the buttons in java file by default showed this.

```
BCel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output=(input-32)*5/9;  
    }
});
BFah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output=1.8*input+32;
    }
});
```

(output=... is obviously written by me)

What I don't understand is why does it show arg0 in the first one and v in the second one.
The other similar questions ask why does it show arg0, arg1, ar2 etc. but I fail to understand this variety.

Will this cause any error in my application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arg0` and `v` are just variable names. You could choose any valid Java identifier.

> *What I don't understand is why does it show arg0 in the first one and v in the second one.*

If you, in Eclipse, choose the option *"Override method in OnClickListener"* or let Eclipse fill in the methods in an anonymous class it will automatically select the same variable name as the overridden methods (and arg*N* if the source code is not attached).

> *Will this cause any error in my application ?*

No, as long as you stick with valid Java identifiers it won't cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Having different names will not cause an error in your application. They are the names of your parameters for those methods.  It is most likely just Eclipse auto-generating a parameter name when you instantiate the anonymous class using `new View.OnClickListener() {...}`, but you could use any valid Java identifier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any difference between arg0 and v . both are just identifier
may be you got error due to
this Statement

```
  output=1.8*input+32;
```

may be casting error etc depending on data type of "input"

Answer (score 0):

You can use any name for variable it does not matter.You are getting error because `input` is undefined symbol. You have to declare it before using it.

Comment: `input` and `output` could be fields of the enclosing class.